# Share button in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-permissions

I created one test publishing site. In that site I created one manage permission level copying contribute permission and checking 'Manage Permission'. I gave the permission to the user on one library and one folder inside that library that manage permission. 
when I as an administrator try to share that folder I see only 'Can View' and 'Can Edit' option while the test user with manage permission can see all permission levels in the site. 
Why is that so? Shouldn't the admin see all the options and the user see only edit and view option.

Answer (score 0):

When users have permission to share a folder in the library, by default, they only can see 'Can View' and 'Can Edit' options.

When users in the site permission page, if they have enough permissions, by default, they can see all permission levels in the site.

Comment: I have a site, a library and a folder. I broke the permission on the folder and gave the user manage permission. on the site and library the user has only read permission. but still while sharing the folder the user is getting all the options.